# Reflection : Get the real type of a initialized auto-property (C#6)

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, c#-6.0

I have a class declared like this :

```
public class MyClass
{
    public IMyInterface1 Prop1 { get; } = new MyImplementation1();
    public IMyInterface2 Prop2 { get; } = new MyImplementation2();
    public IMyInterface3 Prop3 { get; } = new MyImplementation3();
    //[...]
}
```

I would like the list of implemented types, using reflection. 
I dont have an instance of MyClass, just the type.

Ex:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var aList = typeof(MyClass).GetProperties(); // [IMyInterface1, IMyInterface2, IMyInterface3]
    var whatIWant = GetImplementedProperties(typeof(MyClass)); // [MyImplementation1, MyImplementation2, MyImplementation3]
}

IEnumerable<Type> GetImplementedProperties(Type type)
{
    // How can I do that ?
}
```

PS: I'm not sure the title is well adapted, but I have found nothing better. I am open to suggestions.

Comment: If you can't create an instance of the class, there is no easy and reliable way to do it. You can find a constructor of that type, examine its IL (see the Mono.Cecil library) and use the instruction stream to deduce the types that would be assigned to the properties if that constructor was run.

Comment: That isn't really stored in the metadata as such. The compiler transforms the initializers into statements in the constructor, the same way it does with field initializers.

Comment: Ok, but if the compiler transforms the initializer into a field, this field should be retrievable via reflection, right?

Comment: The field would have the type of the interface. There IS no concrete type to read unless the field has been assigned to, and for that to happen SOMEONE needs to have invoked a constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflection is type metadata introspection, thus, it can't get what an actual instance of a given type may contain in their properties unless you provide an instance of the so-called type.

That's the main reason why reflection methods like `PropertyInfo.GetValue` have a first mandatory argument: the instance of the type where the property is declared on.

You're in the wrong direction if you want to use reflection for this. **Actually you need a syntax analyzer** and luckily, C# 6 comes with the new and fancy compiler formerly known as [Roslyn (GitHub repository)](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn). You can also use [NRefactory (GitHub repository)](https://github.com/icsharpcode/NRefactory).

Both can be used to parse actual C# code. You can parse the whole source code and then get what classes are returned in expression-bodied properties.

Comment: Thanks for your response! If the compiler transforms initializers into fields, why this fields aren't retrievable by reflection?

Comment: @Xav987 This fact has nothing to do with the problem. You've never been able to get code expressions using reflection, and you've never been able to get what will happing during run-time using reflection too!!

Comment: @Xav987 And I suspect you can get these fields using reflection, but the type will be your interface and not the implementation :D

Answer (score 0):

You can't get real types without class instance, because properties are initialized only for instances. For instance of the class, you can do something like that

```
List<Type> propertyTypes = new List<Type>();
PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(MyClass).GetProperties();
foreach(PropertyInfo propertyInfo in properties)
{
    propertyTypes.Add(propertyInfo.GetValue(myClassInstance));
}
```